# I want to send the last 10 minute data via bluetooth

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, bluetooth

This was for photocell data logging for 30 sec intervals, now I want to write a code which commands from the cellphone and sends back the last 10 minute data.

At first I thought if I make an array of 20 buckets and put it in a loop, then send the loop function to android would make it right. But it just sends me continues data. I only want the last 10 minute data of the program.

```
float sensorvalue[20];

void setup()
{
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(9600);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        pinMode(sensorvalue, OUTPUT);
    }
}

void loop()
{
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    sendvalues();
    char c;

    if(Serial.available()) {
        c=Serial.read();
        if (c=='t')
            sendvalues();
    }
}

void sendvalues()
{
    for (int i=0 ; i<20 ; i++) {

        Serial.println(sensorvalue);
        sensorvalue   = analogRead(A0);
        delay(30000); //every 30 seconds read data

        if (i>=20) {
            i=0; //reset to beginning of array, so you don't try to save readings outside of the bounds of the array
        }
    }
    Serial.println("***********************************");
}
```

Comment: it reads every 30 seconds. i want to send the last 10 minute data but i'm not sure this is the right way...

Comment: you really should format your code ... it is practically unreadable

Comment: If you want to get/send last 10 minutes of data; first you(your code) have to know how long the transmit is gonna be, and then you can use `millis()` function or an RTS chip to define exactly when you want the data to be sent. basically a count down timer, start for example from 20 minutes and when it reached 10 minutes starts sending the data.

Comment: Thank you so much. The idea of count down sounds fine, but i have one problem. I should receive the last 10 minute data whenever i send for example "m" from my serial port.

Comment: well then start counting whenever you send the letter "m".

Comment: I don't want live data and that's the problem. I need the data that was measured 10 minutes before i send the command. it's either confusing or i'm not on the right road...

Answer (score 1):

What you want for this project is called a [ring buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). Before
reading the rest of this answer, I suggest you stop and take the time to
carefully read the Wikipedia page I am linking to.

Did you read it? Good! Now, yours is a somewhat special case in that you
don't need to continuously keep track of both a read pointer and a write
pointer: you only need the write pointer, as the read happens all in one
big batch.

Once your ring buffer is full, you will start overwriting the oldest
readings, those that are more than 10 minutes old. When the program
is instructed to dump the data, it will send out the whole buffer,
starting with the cell pointed to by the write pointer (the cell that
holds the oldest data point and was about to be overwritten).

There is one special case to take care of. What if the program gets the
command to dump the data while it has less than 20 readings stored?
You could decide that this is a user error, and it's OK for the program
to give garbage. I suggest, however, that the program should be able to
detect this situation, and then only send the valid data. For this, it
needs to store a boolean variable in order to remember whether the
buffer has been filled or not.

Here is an implementation I propose for such a ring buffer, together
with the functions for adding an item and for dumping all the data
through the serial port:

```cpp
const uint32_t READING_PERIOD = 30000;  // one reading every 30 s
const int MAX_READINGS = 20;           // 20 readings = 10 min

int readings[MAX_READINGS];  // ring buffer
uint8_t reding_index = 0;    // next available slot
bool readings_full = false;  // did we fill the ring buffer?

static void register_reading(int value) {
    readings[reding_index] = value;
    if (++reding_index >= MAX_READINGS) {
        readings_full = true;
        reding_index = 0;
    }
}

static void dump_readings() {
    // If the buffer is full, then the next avaiable slot is the oldest
    // reading in the buffer.
    if (readings_full) {
        for (int i = reding_index; i < MAX_READINGS; i++)
            Serial.println(readings[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < reding_index; i++)
        Serial.println(readings[i]);
}
```

Now the main program is quite simple. You time the data taken using the
technique shown in the [Blink without delay](https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay) tutorial. You don't want
to use `delay()` because, when the program is delaying, it cannot
respond to your commands. There is one last question remaining: when it
dumps the data, should it forget it? In other words, if you ask it twice
to dump the data, with less that 10 minutes in between, should it
give repeated data the second time, or should it only provide the fresh
data? In the code below I assume the later option, and thus reset the
buffer, but in the end it is your choice:

```cpp
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    // Periodically take a reading.
    static uint32_t last_reading_time;
    if (millis() - last_reading_time >= READING_PERIOD) {
        last_reading_time += READING_PERIOD;
        register_reading(analogRead(A0));
    }

    // Dump the data on command.
    if (Serial.read() == 't') {
        dump_readings();
        reding_index = 0;       // reset the buffer
        readings_full = false;  // ditto
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much!!!! I've been stuck in this code forever... I think it was too heavy for a newbie..lol

Comment: Can you edit your question to better explain what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make much sense as written.

You need to:

Collect a new value every 30 seconds and save it into an array of values, incrementing a "current value index" variable with each read.

Do you want to trigger the sending of a buffer-full of data when the array is full, or using a command from the remote phone? If you want to trigger the sending from a phone, what would you do if there wasn't a full buffer of data? What would you do if the buffer gets full and there's no command sent from the phone?

Assuming you send a buffer-full of data every time it's available, just wait until the array index reaches the end. When that happens, transmit the entire buffer of data to your phone and reset the array index to start collecting new data.

If you want to trigger sending from your phone you have to handle edge cases like buffer overflow, or trying to send before you have a full buffer of data. I would suggest creating an array larger than you need (say 100 values), making it a ring buffer (google it) and saving new values continuously until the ring buffer is full. If the sketch receives a send command, it could check to see if it has at least 20 values in the buffer, and send those/remove them from the buffer if it does, or send back a "not enough data collected" message if not.

Comment: thank you so much :)